# how to remove ComboBoxes from the previous selection

Tags: c#, winforms

I create method that when a user selects a db table from the combobox, a number of new comboboxes will be generated with each of them shows the table column name. The problem is when I select the second or third db table, the column names associated with those tables are not showed. Instead, the columns of the first table remain exist. Could someone suggest how to remove the comboboxes from the previous selection and show the new ones?

```
private void cboTable_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string tableName = cboTable.SelectedItem.ToString();
            List<string> columnList = GetDatabaseList(tableName);
            
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var column in columnList)
            {
                ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
                cb.Location = new Point(475, 25 * i + 235);

                this.Controls.Add(cb);
                cb.Items.Add(column);
            cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cb.Refresh();
            cb.SelectedIndex = 0;
            
                i++;
             }



    }
```

Comment: You mean you have one ComboBox (`cboTable`), that contains the names of the Tables of a database. Why do you want to create **one** new ComboBox for each Column of a selected Table? What's the use of it (one item per ComboBox)? Maybe you want your `cboTable` selector to fill one ComboBox with all the Column of the Table a user picked. If, for some reason, you want to create a new Control for each Column (a Label, maybe), then each time a new Table is selected, `Dispose()` of all these Controls, rebuild and place them, possibly, in a FlowLayoutPanel or TableLayoutPanel container.

Comment: At this time, you're creating a whole bunch of Controls in the same position, placing them one under the other in a pile (and never dispose of them).

Comment: @Jimi I am still confused how to dispose and rebuild the controls. Could you describe the step by step to do it? Many thanks.

Comment: Can you describe what you're actually trying to do here? Why one ComboBox per Column name? What's the use of these? Do you maybe actually want **one** ComboBox for the Tables names and **one** ComboBox (or a ListBox, eventually) to hold the names of the Columns in that Table?

Comment: @Jimi The program that I am developing now provides functions for uploading excel data into SQL database. My boss requested me that the user should be allowed to see and compare the excel columns and db table columns side by side. That's why I need to show every table columns name in every combobox. Hope this helps you to understand what I am doing now.